how to find lengths of all elements of the dataframe?
As the title say, I tried this:
df_work.with_columns(
    pl.all().str.len_chars()
)

but I got an error

polars.exceptions.SchemaError: invalid series dtype: expected String, got i64


Can you provide a sample data frame?

What if the column is datetime or struct type?

@user459872 Sorry to not make it clear, all elements are just string values. Thank you

please provide sample data for testing

You're leaving something out. zz=pl.DataFrame({     'a':['a','abc','zyc'],     'b':['ee','zz','werg'] }) followed by zz.with_columns(     pl.all().str.len_chars() ) works fine.

@DeanMacGregor Sorry, I thought all are strings but in fact they're not, D.lola's solution works for me.

You are on the right track, however, there is a high prob. that your df might contain non-str values to prevent this, you can just simply cast your data first to String before using the len_chars().
Here is how to do it, I have modified your code, tested it on some arbitrary data since data was not provided.
Modified code:
df_work = df_work.with_columns(pl.all().cast(pl.String).str.len_chars())

Results
shape: (4, 4)
┌──────┬─────┬─────────┬──────────────┐
│ name ┆ age ┆ address ┆ phone number │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---     ┆ ---          │
│ u32  ┆ u32 ┆ u32     ┆ u32          │
╞══════╪═════╪═════════╪══════════════╡
│ 8    ┆ 2   ┆ 8       ┆ 12           │
│ 8    ┆ 2   ┆ 11      ┆ 12           │
│ 11   ┆ 2   ┆ 7       ┆ 12           │
│ 9    ┆ 2   ┆ 7       ┆ 12           │
└──────┴─────┴─────────┴──────────────┘


You nailed it! Thank you!

always happy to help ;)

Minor: pl.all() can be used as syntactic sugar instead of pl.col("*").

Alternatively, apply only to string cols with cs.string() instead of pl.all(), where cs is import polars.selectors as cs
